# How to update numbers in a column given a condition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, error-code, mysql-error-1292

I am updating a table in MySQL with a column of cell phones, where I find badly loaded cell phones. These have less number of numbers than they should. These I need to replace with "0".

I tried it in MySQL version 8.0.3
These were my attempts with code:

--first try

```
UPDATE usuarios_registrados
    SET celular = '0'
    WHERE celular <= 1
    OR celular >= 19999999;
```

--second try

```
UPDATE usuarios_registrados
    SET celular = 0
    WHERE celular
    BETWEEN 1
    AND 19999999;
```

These were the errors:

--first try

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '02392-15635834'    0.204 sec
```

--second try

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '02392-15635834'    0.125 sec
```

Comment: update your question and add your table usuarios_registrados schema

Comment: Give a try with quotes : `UPDATE usuarios_registrados
    SET celular = '0'
    WHERE celular
    BETWEEN '1'
    AND '19999999';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `celular` is a string type column, and you're trying to update by using numeric values, and  problem occurs due to this. Against this problem, creating a cursor within a procedure, and calling it might be a robust way :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Upd_Celular()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_celular   varchar(50);
  DECLARE v_celular2  int;
  DECLARE v_celular3  int;
  DECLARE v_id        int;
  DECLARE finished BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;

  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT id, celular, 
         case when strcmp( cast(celular as signed) , celular ) = 0 then 1 else 0 end 
         as celular2, cast(celular as signed) as celular3
    FROM usuarios_registrados;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = TRUE;

  OPEN cur;

  REPEAT FETCH cur INTO v_id,v_celular,v_celular2,v_celular3;
  IF  NOT finished 
    AND v_celular2 != 0  
    AND v_celular3 BETWEEN 1 AND 19999999
  THEN
    UPDATE usuarios_registrados s
       SET s.celular = '0'
     WHERE s.id = v_id;   
  END IF;

  UNTIL finished END REPEAT;

  CLOSE cur;
END;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fbbc268066da652d83be187fa68fd80f)</kbd>

Comment: @forpas please show the exact code which will not work.

Comment: I mean if celular = '2' then it will not be updated to '0', although I think that this is what the OP wants by the condition `BETWEEN '1' AND '19999999'`.

Comment: '2' is not between '1' and '19999999';

Comment: It shouldn't work, or won't reliably; see [minor adjustments](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=31071ea3e2ea2fca44e4443976e95bf5)

Comment: @FedePosi should "02392-15635834", or any number starting with 0, really be wiped? Are there valid numbers starting with 2 or higher?

Comment: @Uueerdo, they must have at least 8 numbers and start 20000000

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is specifically *"have less number of numbers than they should"*, then this is the most literal expression of that: 
`WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(celular) < expected length`

However, "19999999" suggests "20000000" is valid. If you are sure there are no non-numeric characters, you could try: `WHERE CAST(celular AS SIGNED) BETWEEN 1 AND 19999999`

[CHAR_LENGTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length), [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Edit: Your "incorrect double value" errors suggest you have at least "-" in the column as well, you can use `REPLACE` to remove those for the expression.